# MYSQL - data truncated for column X on update but not on insert

Tags: mysql, database, rdbms

i know there are many questions looking like this one but this one is different; Most of the similar questions are fix by column size increase or were caused by column type mismatch with the data inserted. For my case i have increased the column size form varchar(250) to varchar(1000) and describe  is showing that column is now varchar(1000) but from further investigation i discovered that any attemps to put more that 250 characters in that column that error (but only update is rejected; insert is accepted .... see below).

i have a table CDR_TABLE with more than 10 columns; one of the column ("col_cdata") was of type varchar(250). i changed it to be of type Text. And since then:

Problem:

- all attemps to insert in that table a successfull but any attemps to update a row where the col_cdata has data i receice an error of type [data truncated for column "con_cdata"...]. Even if the update is not on the col_cdata !!!
- I can copy one row having col_cdata value and re-insert it as a new record and it works but an update to any column yield the same error.
- if a copy just the col_cdata value to update another record with empty value on col_cdata, it generates the same error.

How can i debug this ?
Thanks for any hint.

SQL to create the same table :

```
CREATE TABLE `cdr_data` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `col1` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `col2` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `col_cdata` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `col3` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `col4` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `col5` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `col6` mediumtext CHARACTER SET utf8,
  `col7` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `col8` enum('a','b') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'a',
  `col9` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `col10` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT '1',
  `col11` float NOT NULL,
  `col12` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `col13` enum('c','d','e') DEFAULT 'c',
  `col14` text,
  `col15` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `col16` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `col17` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `col18` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `col19` enum('d','success','e') DEFAULT 'success',
  `col20` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col21` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `col22` text,
  `col23` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col24` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col25` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Updates :
(1) I have reduced the data to insert in the column and increase it step by step. The problem when i put more than 250 characters; so it means: - the alter from varchar(250) to varchar(1000) seems to have worked but really did not work; if i do desc col_cdata i see varchar(1000) but if length is more than 250 i have all the describe problems.
(2) I dont know what code is needed: Original col_cdat size is 250; i atered it to 1000 ; describe  shows that now it is varchar(1000); an insert of a new row size 256 characters in col_cdata is accepted but any attempts to update any column of that row is throwing:

```
Error: ER_DATA_TOO_LONG: Data too long for column 'custom_data' at row 1
```

in the logs, the row is inserted); after the insert any update of any column of that row is failing with that error but is time the update is rejected. (Insert is accepted but update is rejected).

Fundamentally: why after increase ofd the column from varchar(250) to varchar(1000) an insert is accepted but an update is rejected ?

Comment: create a new Column and copy the data, delete the ld and try to update that

Comment: Post your queries and table structure, otherwise we don’t know what’s really going on

Comment: the problen coud be the version number, can you after a backup update it?

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: Any triggers running after update?

Comment: Your edits help. But you haven't given us text we can cut & paste & run to get your error(s). Also this is hard to read. Don't try to cram everything into 1 word, phrase or sentence. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. PS  Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers.

Comment: But did you search per my comment. (And I posted that standard prefab comment about searching because generally speaking, people are poor at searching. Also clearly we can expect your problem to be a faq.) PS You really need to give a [mre]. If you tried various things, code for each would help.

Comment: @HoneyboyWilson thank you so much millions of times ! That was the problem; there was an beforeUpdate trigger to save the row before updating it the row and the size increase was not applied to the mirror table used in the trigger. Please post it as an answer so i can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to change column type to LONGTEXT?

Comment: Thanks  @Rachel Watson i had tried that also but the problem was a trigger beforeUpdate and i forgot to increase the size of the column in the mirror table